# how to modify python complex number

Tags: python, complex-numbers, readonly

Once created, Python complex numbers are read-only.

```
>>> x = complex(1,1)
>>> x
(1+1j)
>>> x.real=2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: readonly attribute
```

How do I modify a complex number in Python without constructing a new complex? This seems like an unnecessary limitation. Any ideas why complex was implemented like this?

Comment: pretty much for the same reason you can't do `a = 4` and then `a.real = 10`.

Comment: @DJV No, in your example it would also magically change the type, which is even worse.

Comment: @delnan how about you try `dir(4)` or `print (4).imag` before you jump to conclusions?

Comment: @DJV A type is not only defined by what its `__dir__` method returns (yes, that's really what `dir` calls) or what attributes it supports (though often, that is enough -- cf. duck typing). Check `type(4)` versus `type(1j)`, or just note their very different behavior for various operations such as `math.sqrt`. 4 is an integer, which happens to say it doesn't have a imaginary component. A complex number is not an integer, neither mathematically nor in Python.

Comment: @delnan And how exactly does `a.real = 10` change the type? Or did you simply not get my comment? The idea was that one cannot do the same for integers and floats (not only for comples), despite they have `.real` and `.imag` as well.

Comment: @DJV An integer (which we seem to agree is a separate type) always has a imaginary components of zero, if you consider the concept meaningful for integers at all. A number with a non-zero imaginary component is not an integer but a complex number, so you'd have to change its type to `complex` (or make *everything* a complex number to begin with). You can expose a read-only attribute for limited interoperability (in other contexts too; consider the children of a leaf node in a tree) but still be mutable in other ways.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26478/discussion-between-djv-and-delnan)

Answer (score 4):

All numbers in Python (and strings, too) are immutable. This makes computation easier in several ways (i.e. it makes the Python interpreter more performant) and generally doesn't cause much trouble.

To reuse values from another value, you can just do that, of course:

```
x = complex(2, x.imag)
```

Comment: A lot of other things are immutable too. Tuples and all cases of namedtuples, for instance. Some other collections too (`frozenset` comes to mind, though that seems to be rather obscure). Not to mention non-standard-library types, though my immutable types usually end up as namedtuples.

Comment: I frequently use frozensets as dictionary keys. It is in fact pretty rare for me to use any kind of sequence type as an "accumulator", preferring iterators and list list/dictionary/set - comprehensions, so mutable sequences are rare in my code (I will of course return lists of homogeneous items merely for convention's sake). It depends on the problem domain.

Comment: +1: Excellent answer.  Short and to the point, giving the details that are useful for this question (rather than an detailed exposition on all immutable types as the comments above seem to prefer).

Comment: While I think djc's answer is good, I completely disagree with tom10's assessment. The OP asked 1) Q: How do I modify a complex number without constructing a new one A: You don't and 2) Q: why are complex numbers implemented in this way? A: They are an immutable type, like all other numerics.

Comment: @tom10 I think I've addressed your concerns in the edit of my answer above. Please take a look and re-evaluate your vote.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons for Python's immutable numbers:

1) It economizes memory by allowing multiple variables to point the same object:

```
>>> x = 3 + 4j
>>> y = x
>>> x is y
True
```

2) Immutability goes hand-in-hand with hashability.  It makes numbers suitable for use as dictionary keys and elements of sets:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[3 + 4j] = 'red'
>>> d[3 + 4j]
'red'
```

3) With Python's custom memory management, these objects tend to get re-used rather than being repeatedly allocated and freed.  This mitigates the cost of "creating new objects".

Answer (score 1):

*In Brief:*

> How do I modify a complex number in Python without constructing a new
>   complex?

You don't. You may either use elements of the old complex number (if you find yourself doing this often, you could write a function to do so) or create a complex number class of your own.

> Any ideas why complex was implemented like this?

Complex numbers are a numeric type and, like all python numeric types, are immutable.

*Longer explanation:*

You can't modify an `int`, a `float`, a `namedtuple`, or a `frozenset` any more than you can modify a complex number. Complex numbers are immutable which comes with advantages (one of the most important among them is that you can use complex numbers as dictionary keys). Most of the operations you would perform with complex numbers are still mathematical and therefore lend themselves to immutability (like all of the other numeric types). If this is not the case, consider creating your own class, possibly with a `__slots__` attribute.

My advice: some developers strive for immutability in their data structures. It makes programming and debugging substantially less complicated. Complex numbers in python were well designed.